# Jupyter Notebook skips cells

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have been using Jupyter Notebook for a while. However, it has started to do strange things. When I 'Run All', it has a tendency to skip the executing of certain cells. This of course causes the notebook to fail as some variables are not being defined.

I am not sure how to provide a working example of this, as I am certain it is not my code as it used to work fine. Does anyone have any ideas what I could be causing this? I used to have Notebook version 5.7, but I downgraded to 5.6 with still the same issue.

Any help would be great.

BJR.

Comment: Hey, same here. It used to work and now sometimes it skips cells (usually causing the next cells to cell, luckily).

I'm running Jupyter on Windows 10, running Jupyter 4.4 and Notebook 5.6.

I will open an issue on Github ASAP.

Comment: Same here on Win 10, Python 3.6.6, Jupyter 4.4.0 and Notebook 5.7.0.

Comment: I think there is an issue with the Ipykernel.

Comment: [see here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4090)